# VirusTotal URL Analysis Report API

Tags: javascript, virus-scanning

Using the sample JavaScript code from https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/url-info,
I tried to retrieve information for URL scanning:

1st API run to get the URL analysis id:

```
const apiKey = {api-key};

console.log("testing in progress");

const data = 'url={urlToScan}';
var response;

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var id =response.data.id;
        console.log(id);
        getReport(id.trim());
    }
});

xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls');
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-apikey', apiKey);
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

xhr.send(data);
```

2nd API run to get the URL report, using the ID obtained from the 1st API:

```
const data = null;
const apiKey = {api-key};

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open('GET', "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls/"+id);
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-apikey', apiKey);

xhr.send(data);
```

However, the second API returns a 404 error:
[image: Error returned by second API]

I'm not sure where does the additional '===' comes from as I've already used trim() on the id.

Any help is much appreciated!, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in 1st step and also mentioned in https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/scan-url, what you receive when scanning the URL is an analysis ID, not a URL ID.

Then you'll have to use `/api/v3/analyses/{id}` (https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/analysis) instead of `/api/v3/urls/{id}` to retrieve the analysis.

If you want to retrieve the URL report directly from the analysis ID instead of the state of the analysis you can use the `item` relationship of the analysis (https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/item) by doing `GET /api/v3/analyses/{id}/item`.